# Executing JS-Code in Vaadin 14 Application does nothing

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

I am trying to make a simple scroll down happen when the page is loaded.

```
@Route("somthing")
public class SomeView extends VerticalLayout{

public SomeView(){
    ...
    Adding some Elements
    ...

    UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("window.scroll(0,300)");
}
}
```

I also tried adding a listener to the window:

```
 UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("window.addEventListener('onload', function(){console.log('trigger');window.scroll(0,300);});");
```

But in both cases simply nothing happens when the page is loaded.

Comment: I'm assuming the second one doesn't trigger because the `window`'s `load` event has already fired at this point.

Comment: For another example of executing arbitrary JavaScript from the server-side of a Vaadin 14 app, see the Question, [*How to Print in Vaadin Flow?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58754154/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Olli mentioned in the comments, the second one doesn't work because the onload event has already happened at the time you add the eventlistener.

I believe the first one doesn't work because the `SomeView` was not attached yet to the page (as you execute the js in the constructor), therefore the page has not enough content to be scrollable yet.
You should execute that javascript in the `onAttach` method of the View.

```
@Route("somthing")
public class SomeView extends VerticalLayout{

    public SomeView(){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("window.scroll(0,300)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use **getElement()** instead of *UI.getCurrent().getPage()*

```
@Route("something")
public class SomeView extends VerticalLayout{

  public SomeView(){
    ...
    Adding some Elements
    ...

    getElement().executeJs("window.scroll(0,300)");
  }
}
```

in the contructor of your **SomeView**.

Comment: @[tobias-nolte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6044734/tobias-nolte): You are welcome. Thank you  too